# Page is showing two scrollbars

Tags: html, css

In my page is showing two times scrollbar on right of browser. I want only one scrollbar. Can any help me? Thank for every answer.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("images/background.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#header {
    position:relative;
    width:900;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.bluepanel{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:900;
    height:50;
    background-image: url("images/bluepanel.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.headertxt{
    position:absolute;
    width:635;
    height:21;
    background-image: url("images/headertxt.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    left:40px;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
#container{
    position:relative;
    height:50;
    top:0px;
    width:900;
}
#container2{
    position:relative;
    height:93;
    width:900;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:0;
}
.graypanel{
    position:absolute;
    width:900;
    height:105;
    background-image: url("images/graypanel.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    top:-12;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
#container3{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:67;
    top:-30px;
    width:900;
}
.bluepanel_2{
    position:absolute;
    height:67;
    width:900;
    background-image: url("images/bluepanel_2.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.hlavny_text{
    position:relative;
    top:5;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
#container4{
    position:relative;
    height:352;
    width:900;
    top:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.bodyimage{
    position:absolute;
    height:352;
    width:900;
    top:-30px;
    display:block;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
#container5{
    position:relative;
    height:283;
    width:900;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:-10;
}
.lightblue{
    position:absolute;
    height:377;
    width:900;
    top:-20;
    background-image: url("images/lightblue.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    width:173;
    height:77;
    left:20px;
    top:3px;
}
#htxt{
    position:absolute;
    right:700px;
    top:15px;
}
#menu{
    position:relative;
    left:250px;
    top:27px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.navrhy_rieseni{
    position:relative;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
}
.navrhy_rieseni:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.whiteline{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:-7px;
    background-color:white;
    width:1;
    height:42;
}
#menu2{
    position:relative;
    left:400px;
    top:-27;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.efektivnejsie_osvetlenie{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
}
.efektivnejsie_osvetlenie:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.whiteline2{
    position:absolute;
    left:250px;
    top:-12px;
    background-color:white;
    width:1;
    height:42;
}
#menu3{
    position:relative;
    left:650px;
    top:-95;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.fotovoltaika{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
.fotovoltaika:hover{    
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.trans_blue{
    position:absolute;
    width:487;
    height:44;
    background-image: url("images/trans_blue.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    right:20px;
    top:95px;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.trans_blue_txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:410px;
    top:82px;
    color:white;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.lightgray{
    position:absolute;
    width:498;
    height:94;
    background-image: url("images/light_gray.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    right:55px;
    top:139px;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.txt_lightgray{
    position:absolute;
    left:410px;
    top:156px;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
}
.image{
    position:absolute;
    width:335;
    height:224;
    display:block;
    left:45px;
    top:-70px;
}
.nase_sluzby_nadpis{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:80px;
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; 
}
.povieme_vam_txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:40px;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;     
}
.bluepanel3{
    position:absolute;
    height:44;
    width:487;
    background-image: url("images/bluepanel_2.png"),none;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    right:25px;
    top:0px;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.panel3_txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:-9px;
    color:white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;     
}
.nase_sluzby_txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:115px;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; 
}
.vyhody_led_nadpis{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:215px;
    color:black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;         
}
.vyhody_led_txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:250px;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; 
}
.footer{
    position:relative;
    width:900;
    height:250;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:50px;
}
.footercontainer{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:45px;
}
.footerimg{
    position:absolute;
    width:121;
    height:44;
    top:30px;
}
.adresy{
    position:absolute;
    top:87px;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; 
}
.rwegroup{
    position:absolute;
    top:160px;
}
.footerline{
    position:absolute;
    height:170;
    width:1;
    background-color: white;
    background-size:cover;
    display:block;
    left:150px;
    top:17px;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
}
.blue_txt{
    position:absolute;
    left:230px;
    top:25px;
    color:#0c57a6;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; 
}
.kontakt{
    position:absolute;
    left:230px;
    top:87px;
    color:black;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; 
}
#cont{
    position:relative;
    left:400px;
    width:500px;
    height:0px;
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see what you are doing.

Comment: Surely you can eliminate part of the CSS. Either that'll give you a smaller example, or it'll show you what exactly causes your problem.

Comment: I deleted the `w` 's . If they were necessary, revert. Well, actually [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because there is a div somewhere in your body that is overflowing. If you can find that div, and change it to `overflow:hidden;` then it should get rid of the extra scrollbar.